# How do I remove the wrapping div from a Form input of type select-multiple

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have two tables in my database "cars" and "car_types". "cars" table refers to "car_types" by "car_type_id". For example "car_types" has 2 fields "id" and "car_type". It also has 3 entries "new", "used dealer", "used private". How can I show these 3 entries as checkbox in my view.

I'm trying to adjust the output from:

```
foreach ($car_types as $car_type)                       
{
     $car_type_new[$car_type['CarType']['id']]=$car_type['CarType']['car_type'];
}                   
echo $this->Form->input('Car.car_type_id',array('div'=>false,'multiple'=>'checkbox','options'=>$car_type_new,'style'=>"margin-left:20px; padding:0;"));
```

I also want to remove the wrapper div around each checkbox.

Each checkbox is output by the Form helper like so, even if the div => false option is set:

```
<input type="hidden" id="CarCarTypeId" value="" name="data[Car][car_type_id]">

<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="CarCarTypeId1" value="1" name="data[Car][car_type_id][]"><label for="CarCarTypeId1">New</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="CarCarTypeId2" value="2" name="data[Car][car_type_id][]"><label for="CarCarTypeId2">Used Dealer</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="CarCarTypeId3" value="3" name="data[Car][car_type_id][]"><label for="CarCarTypeId3">Used Private
</label></div>
```

the div => false option only removes the div wrapped around the entire collection of checkboxes, not each checkbox.

Any Ideas on how I could remove the div that wraps around each checkbox? And please do tell me if I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the API, you can use the `after` and `before` array options to control what goes before and after the `<input>` and `<label>` pair. Here is the [documentation on the input function](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#automagic-form-elements) or the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-FormHelper.html#_input)

Alternatively, you you could use the [checkbox function](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#checkbox) ([API](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-FormHelper.html#_checkbox)) in the Form helper to get around it

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is about CakePHP 1.3, but I found this while searching on the Internet, so I'll share the solution that worked for me anyway.

You can pass a corresponding key to the `$options` for the `input()` helper function:

```
'div'=>false
```

More info: http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-FormHelper.html#_input